# How do I import Airflow operators for version 2.2.5?

Tags: airflow, google-cloud-composer

I have just upgraded my Airflow to 2.2.5 and I can't use the EmptyOperator. It should be simple `from airflow.operators.empty import EmptyOperator`but I get the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'airflow.operators.empty'`. I also tried:

```
from airflow.operators import empty
from empty.operators import EmptyOperator
```

The Airflow repo itself shows the structure that would mean
`from airflow.operators.empty import EmptyOperator` should work but it doesn't so I am really puzzled as to what is going on.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`EmptyOperator` was released in Airflow 2.3.0.

In Airflow 2.3.0 `DummyOperator` was deprecated in favor of `EmptyOperator` (See [PR](https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/22832))

For Airflow>=2.3.0 you should use `EmptyOperator`:

```
from airflow.operators.empty import EmptyOperator
```

For Airflow<2.3.0 you should use `DummyOperator`:

```
from airflow.operators.dummy import DummyOperator
```